# Unity serializedObject.FindProperty returning null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to display the QuestSO objects in Unity inspector, and I dont know how to access the elements, in such a way that i will be able to use

```
EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(listProperty)
```

this is my QuestSO class

```cs
    [System.Serializable]

    public class QuestSO : ScriptableObject
    {
        [field: SerializeField] public List<int> listt  {get;set;}= new List<int> { 69, 420 ,123,2345};
        [field: SerializeField] public int a {get;set;}  = 3;
```

and code where I am trying to get the property:

```cs
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnEnable");
        
        _questSo = (QuestSO)target;

        SerializedObject serializedObject = new SerializedObject(_questSo);

        SerializedProperty aProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("a");
        SerializedProperty listProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty("listt");

        if(aProperty == null){
            Debug.Log("a null");
        }
        if(listProperty == null){
            Debug.Log("list null");
        }
    }
```

and both of them are returning null

Comment: why not just QuestSO.a or QuestSO.listt?

Comment: @BugFinder you don't want to do that in custom inspectors .. always stick to `SerializedProperty` as much as possible ... direct accesses to fields etc of the `target` get pretty messy regarding the marking *dirty* and thereby also Undo/Redo, saving etc .. need to handle it all manually if you do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get null for each of your objects properties is because they are c# properties.

This seems a bit counterintuitive, because the function is called `FindProperty`, but it is used on fields.

Change your property definitions to fields and it will work.

```
public class QuestSO : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<int> listt = new List<int> { 69, 420 ,123,2345};
    public int a = 3;
}
```

Comment: In cases where you really want/need to stick to properties (e.g. quite useful for restricting modifications) you can totally stick to  the serialized auto-properties if you know how, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76537888/7111561)

Answer (score 1):

In general there is no need to cast to a specific type in your Inspector.

It already has a build in `serializedObject` for the current `target` anyway ;)

---

Then as was already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76534398/7111561) what you have there are **properties** and Unity doesn't serialize those by default.

The attribute `[field: SerializeField]` is pretty much a hack which in the background actually causes a "hidden"(virtual) backing field to be generated and serialized.

The naming also is pretty hacky as e.g.

```
[field: SerializeField] public List<int> listt  {get;set;}= new List<int> { 69, 420 ,123,2345};
[field: SerializeField] public int a {get;set;}  = 3;
```

results in the two backing fields generated with name

```
<listt>k__BackingField
<a>k__BackingField
```

So knowing this you can sure stick to properties and in your Inspector use

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    Debug.Log("OnEnable");
    
    // Redundant
    //_questSo = (QuestSO)target;
    //SerializedObject serializedObject = new SerializedObject(_questSo);

    var aProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty($"<{nameof(QuestSO.a)}>k__BackingField");
    var listProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty($"<{nameof(QuestSO.listt)}>k__BackingField");

    if(aProperty == null){
        Debug.Log("a null");
    }
    if(listProperty == null){
        Debug.Log("list null");
    }
}
```

For more information see [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/c-7-3-field-serializefield-support.573988/page-2#post-7622821) where they also made an extension method for this:

> ```
> public static class SerializedObjectExtensions
> {
>     public static SerializedProperty FindAutoProperty(this SerializedObject @this, string name)
>     {
>         return @this.FindProperty(GetBackingFieldName(name));
>     }
>  
>     public static SerializedProperty FindAutoPropertyRelative(this SerializedProperty @this, string name)
>     {
>         return @this.FindPropertyRelative(GetBackingFieldName(name));
>     }
>  
>     static string GetBackingFieldName(string name)
>     {
>     #if NET_STANDARD || NET_STANDARD_2_1
>         return string.Create(1/*<*/ + name.Length + 16/*>k__BackingField*/, name, static (span, name) =>
>         {
>             span[0] = '<';
>             name.AsSpan().CopyTo(span[1..]);
>             ">k__BackingField".AsSpan().CopyTo(span[(name.Length + 1)..]);
>         });
>     #else
>         return '<' + name + ">k__BackingField";
>     #endif
>     }
> }
> ```

which I personally would probably simplify to

```
return $"<{name}>k__BackingField";
```

---

Little Demo:

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class QuestSO : ScriptableObject
{
    // NOTE: In general using auto-properties only makes sense in cases where you actually want to restrict the setter
    // if this is not the case you would simply use fields instead
    [field: SerializeField]
    public List<int> listt { get; private set; } = new List<int> { 69, 420, 123, 2345 };

    [field: SerializeField]
    public int a { get; private set; } = 3;
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(QuestSO))]
public class QuestSOEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty listt;
    private SerializedProperty a;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        listt = serializedObject.FindAutoProperty(nameof(QuestSO.listt));
        a = serializedObject.FindAutoProperty(nameof(QuestSO.a));
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(listt);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Clear list"))
        {
            listt.arraySize = 0;
        }
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(a);

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}

public static class SerializedObjectExtensions
{
    public static SerializedProperty FindAutoProperty(this SerializedObject @this, string name)
    {
        return @this.FindProperty(GetBackingFieldName(name));
    }
 
    public static SerializedProperty FindAutoPropertyRelative(this SerializedProperty @this, string name)
    {
        return @this.FindPropertyRelative(GetBackingFieldName(name));
    }

    private static string GetBackingFieldName(string name)
    {
        return $"<{name}>k__BackingField";
    }
}
```

[image]